# Use a get or post on same action, but only ValidateAntiForgeryToken on post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can set up an action that accepts get or post requests with:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get|HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

And I can get it to check the forgery token with

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

But how do I get it to only test the token on posts, not gets?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Validating GET requests is generally a good idea. Otherwise just overload the methods?

Comment: Is it actually a good idea to use a token for every single url on a site when they don't change any data on the backend?

Comment: you try removing the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute and then check if the request is a post, if so call `AntiForgery.Validate()`?

Comment: Ahh, I can call that manually. Will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have 2 separate actions, one that accepts Get, the other accepts Post and checks token.